# Is "Signature themes" the same as "Signature tunes"?

Tags: expressions

I wonder if "Signature themes" is the same as "Signature tunes". It's from the book I'm translating. And this is the context:

> Answering the first question is at the core of my professional life. After that meeting, I significantly increased my exhortations to companies on the importance of follow- up after they train their employees. It’s one of my signature themes: People don’t get better without follow-up. So let’s get better at following up with our people.

Comment: A "theme" may be many things, including a musical motif; but in this context the word has nothing to do with music. It means something like a "constantly repeated maxim or aphorism". A 'signature' theme would be one which is closely associated with a specific speaker. The author is saying 'That "people don't get better without follow-up" is a core principle of the method I have invented, and I say it over and over.'

Answer (score 2):

*Signature* is a tricky word in English. NOAD lists a few different meanings, but the one that is pertinent here is:

> **a distinctive pattern, product, or characteristic by which someone or something can be identified** : [as adj.] *his signature dish*.

So, using the dictionary's example, a *signature dish* would be one that the chef is most well-known for, and most associated with.

If an athlete is particularly adept at using a certain move to get around a defender, for example, that might become known as his *signature move*:

> The [skyhook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mcsciCQjw4) was Kareem Abdul-Jabbar's [signature move](http://www.allaboutbasketball.us/nba/7-most-unforgettable-signature-moves-in-nba-history.html).

If a comedian becomes famous for one particular joke, and uses it a lot, that might become his signature line:

> Rodney Dangerfield's [signature line](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A13343-2004Oct6.html) was: “[I don't get no respect.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZCVR_ajL_Eo)”

And one [news article](http://www.legalnews.com/Macomb/1405595) noted:

> Flamboyant [glasses and outfits](http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/9/25/1411664684210/Elton-John-in-1977-012.jpg) have been part of Elton John's signature look.

In the book you're translating, the author writes:

> *It’s one of my signature themes: People don’t get better without follow-up*.

Some people have certain maxims that they try to live by, and perhaps quote. It might be an encouraging person who tries to "help somebody smile every day," or a driven person who says, "Set your alarm clock 30 minutes early, so you can get out of bed and do something" – those could be called *personal themes*. And if someone gets known for ascribing to such a theme, that might become a signature theme.

The author is saying that he's come to realize the importance of follow-up, and it's become a signature theme. Therefore, if that author offered me some advice, I'd expect that he'd follow-up with me sometime over the next several days.

<sup>If you take a look at my [profile](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/113/j-r?tab=profile), you'll see that "context is everything" has become a signature theme of mine.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

*Signature Tune* is a synonym for *Theme Music*. Both are overheard when, for example, the host of a show enters the room. It also works both ways: the Theme can be played first, letting the audience know that the host is soon to arrive (i.e. Building Tension or Excitement).

If you want to use a musical metaphor to describe your belief in "following up" then I recommend this:

> LEITMOTIF
>
> [ˈlītmōˌtēf]
>
> NOUN
>
> 1.a recurrent theme throughout a musical or literary composition, associated with a particular person, idea, or situation.

Just like Haile always says, "Following Up is my Leitmotif."

Comment: This is not correct, even when limited to music. The "theme song" is the music played at the opening and closing of a program, or at other key moments such as the entry of a host. aA Signature tune or song is a song particularly associated with a performer, and often played by that performer. "Sounds of Silence" was a signature tune for Simon & Garfunkel. A "musical theme" is indeed a synonym for "Leitmotif", which is yet a third thing.